# Приниципиально ли использовать SQL для небольших проектов?

Tags: база-данных, php, интернет-магазин, sql

Пробую писать подобие интернет магазина на **php**(заодно учу), данные удобно хранить в **CSV**, около тысячи товаров, скажем такого формата:

```
Артикул;Радиус;Фото;Вылет;Болты;Фирма;Гарантия;Склад;Цвет;Цена

1;16;1.jpeg;6;4;Yokohama;6;4;1;2999
2;16;2.jpeg;4;4;Yokohama;4;4;1;3999
3;17;3.jpeg;33;4;Bridgestone;33;4;1;4999
4;17;4.jpeg;34;5;Goddyyear;34;5;1;5250
5;15;5.jpeg;45;4;Medved;45;5;1;4456
```

читаю из файла таким образов:

```
$f = fopen("file.csv", "rt") or exit("Ошибка загрузки базы данных!");
$header=fgetcsv($f,1000,";");
```

и дальше цикл. Скажите ваше мнение:

**- корректно ли это?** С виду всё работает неплохо, не тормозит.

**- если рациональнее использовать SQL то почему?** или нет разницы?

**- не сильно ли будет грузить сервер такой метод?** или SQL будет легче?

Comment: Молчу о `Join-ax, процедурах,триггерах,функциях...` А если у вас миллионы таблицы, как вы будете обрабатывать ? Учите SQL, без него никуда.

Comment: @Олег_Б если и проект маленький, и посещений будет так себе, то можно оставить. Но при дальнейшем росте бд всё равно потребуется.

Comment: @Vtvtnjd `А если у вас миллионы таблицы` -- хороший ответ на вопрос о небольших проектах. Файлы могут быть вполне приемлемым вариантом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот лично мне было бы лень. Просто потому, что любая операция требует подробного ручного описания действий. [@ЫЫЫ](/users/7285/%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B) привёл примеры, а представьте, что нужно удалить всё с радиусом 16. Писать код для прогулки по массиву и перепаковки его в новый? А если фоток не одна, а произвольное число на товар? А если товаров не сто, а... Впрочем, это уже лишнее :)

Плюс, минус :) такого подхода ещё и в том, что чем больше кода приходится на одно действие, тем больше потенциальных точек возникновения глюков. Особенно при масштабировании проекта (неважно в какую сторону) или изменениях в структурах данных. Поддержка такого проекта может вырасти в большую проблему.

В общем, резюме: пока всё это устраивает лично вас - делайте как хотите и не спрашивайте ничьих советов. Никто не заставляет вас использовать SQL, более того, есть случаи, когда использование файлов куда эффективней. Но не говорите, что вас не предупреждали :)

Answer (score 6):

К вашему вопросу использования такого подхода:

- Напишите код получающий количество
     товаров по радиусу;
- Напишите код    получающий количество
     товаров по    фирме;
- Напишите код получающий    среднюю
     цену товара по фирме;
- Напишите код получения 10 самых 
     дорогих товаров;
- Сделайте наценку товаров фирмы
     Yokohama на 2.3%;

И т.д. и т.п.
И тогда возможно станет ясно стоит ли оставлять такой подход,  или воспользоваться БД.